# Validation works in the browser but doesn't work in the console. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, console, rails-console

I have the following custom validation:

**app/validators/clock_able_validator.rb**

```
class ClockAbleValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    time_tracker = time_tracker(record)
    error_location = "activerecord.errors.models.activity.attributes.base"
    record.errors[:clock_in_able] = I18n.t "#{error_location}.clock_in_able" if !clock_in_able?(record,time_tracker)
    record.errors[:clock_out_able] = I18n.t "#{error_location}.clock_out_able" if !clock_out_able?(record,time_tracker)
  end

  def clock_in_able?(record,time_tracker)
    return true if time_tracker.nil?
    return true if !time_tracker.clock_out.nil?
    return true if time_tracker.id == record.id
    return false
  end

  def clock_out_able?(record,time_tracker)
    return false if record.id == time_tracker.id and !time_tracker.clock_out.nil?
    return true if !record.clock_in.nil? 
    return false
  end

  def time_tracker(record)
    TimeTracker.find_all_by_activity_id(record.activity_id).last || TimeTracker.new
  end
end
```

The **time_tracker** is just the previous record. The new record is validated given that certain conditions involving the previous record are met.

This validation work perfectly when I test it in the browser. My question is: why does the validation not work when I test it in the console? I can save any record in the database from the console.

**[EDIT]**

If I add a different error such as `record.errors[:bla] = "Why only this error works?"`. The validation doesn't pass in the console either. So it works as expected. It passes for the other validations though and it shouldn't.

**[EDIT 2]**

If I start with a fresh database. Trying to save a TimeTracker object that has a value only for the `:clock_out` attribute and not for the `:clock_in` attribute in the browser and everywhere else but the console it fails because it does not pass validation. `TimeTracker.find_all_by_activity_id(record.activity_id).last` returns nil so time_tracker gets the value of TimeTracker.new. so the validation fails. In the console though it gets saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are running the Rails console under the same environment as the server? If, for example, your server was running in production mode, but the console was running in development, they could be querying different databases. Then `TimeTracker.find_all_by_activity_id` would return different results.

Comment: I am in the development environment. TimeTracker.all gives me the same data. It works when I test with RSpec as well. The validation works as it is supposed everywhere but in the console... It doesn't hurt me at all now I just don't understand why that happens and I hope it will not affect the app down the line. I will update an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe the object was passing validation because I didn't reload the console :| I just tried it again and validation doesn't pass anymore. I really though i reloaded the console though. Thanks for your input!